# plotrix graphic and ggplot2 graphic side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine base and ggplot graphics in R figure window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window)

I'd like to plot side by side a plotrix graphic and a ggplot2 graphic. how could I do ? 
Below is an unsuccessful attempt (`gg1`does not appear in the figure).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plotrix)

Mvalues <- matrix(rpois(9,1), ncol=3)
Mcolors <- matrix(rpois(9,5), ncol=3)

g1 <- color2D.matplot(x=Mvalues, show.values=2, cellcolors=Mcolors, 
        xlab="x", ylab="y", axes=FALSE, vcex=0.4)
gg1 <- grob(g1) 
gg2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge") 

grid.arrange(gg1,gg2,ncol=2)
```

Comment: @Andrie Thanks. The second solution works well (I have not tried the first one since it is more complicated). I vote to close too.

Comment: Stephane, since you posted this, you can delete the question if you desire.