# can you save the output of plotrix to an object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to combine a plotrix chart with a ggplot chart uisng grid.arrange.

I can save the image of the ggplot2 using this:

```
p<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=xyl, y=mgp)) + geom_point()

library(plotrix)
slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 16, 8) 
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")
pie3D(slices,labels=lbls,explode=0.1, main="Pie Chart of Countries
```

how would I save the output of  pie3d to p1 and use grid.arrange(p, p1)?

Comment: I think you just need to adjust for your needs answers given in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window)

Comment: Standard Comment:  please do not use pie charts. Ever.  No matter what. Their information-to-space (or -to-ink) ratio is the lowest of any chart type out there.