# Concentric rings in pie chart as vertex of a network using R

Tags: r, igraph, pie-chart

I did post this last week, but I didn't explain it properly, I hope that some of you can help me this time...

I am trying to draw multilayer concentric rings as vertex of a graph.

Here you can find a simple version of what I [did](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~nvau687/p.pdf), and here what what I [want to do](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~nvau687/concentric.pdf). Note that the edge should also be dragged with the vertex.

This is the code for the former:

```
library(igraph)
g=graph.empty(4)
g[1,2]=T
g[3,4]=T
resColors=matrix(as.character(list("green","red","green","green","green","grey","grey",  "green","green","green","red","red","green","green","green","green","red","red","green","green")), nrow=vcount(g))
colors = list()
values = list()
for (i in 1:vcount(g)) {
   values[[i]] = rep(1, times = ncol(resColors))
   colors[i] = list(resColors[i,])
}
size=c(60,50,30,20)
plot(g, vertex.shape = "pie", vertex.pie = values, vertex.pie.color = colors, vertex.size = size)
```

Thanks, Nat

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but this code creates overlapping concentric pie charts: `layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1), nrow=3)); pie(x=c(0.5,0.3,0.2)); pie(x=c(0.4,0.25,0.35))`

Comment: This code creates four pie charts, two of which are concentric.  However, I am not sure how to add in the arrows: `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1)); layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,0, 1,2,1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,3,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,4,0), nrow=6, byrow=TRUE)); pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1)); pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1));
pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1)); pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1));`

Comment: Also, take a look at the following page in the igraph docs: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/igraph.vertex.shapes.html . It essentially tells you how to create custom vertex shapes for igraph. Chances are that you have to create a custom pie chart drawer function and then pass that to `add.vertex.shape` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I though, in case someone else needs the answer:

Before plotting, you call a layout, fruchterman.reingold as an example:

```
lay <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
```

Then you edit lay, in the example, you want node 3 on node 1:

```
lay[3,] <- lay[1,]
```

And finally you plot with the edited layout:

```
plot(g, vertex.shape = "pie", vertex.pie = values, vertex.pie.color = colors, 
     vertex.size = size, layout = lay)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started in base R.  You would need to play around with the layout and arrows more if you want the arrows to touch the pie charts.

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1)); 
layout(matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                1,1,1,1,6,6,0, 
                1,2,2,5,5,6,0, 
                1,2,2,1,0,0,0, 
                1,1,1,3,0,0,0, 
                0,0,0,0,3,0,0, 
                0,0,0,0,0,3,4, 
                0,0,0,0,0,4,4), nrow=9, byrow=TRUE)); 

pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1), labels = NA); 
pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1), labels = NA); 

plot(x=1, y=1, type='n', axes = FALSE, xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,100))
arrows(x0=0, y0=100, x1 = 80, y1 = 20, length=0.25)

pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1), labels = NA); 

plot(x=1, y=1, type='n', axes = FALSE, xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,100))
arrows(x0=0, y0=0, x1 = 80, y1 = 90)

pie(x=c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1), labels = NA);
```

[image]

Alternatively, maybe there is a way to mix and match plots and images from different packages that can help in this case.  See here: [Combine base and ggplot graphics in R figure window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window)

EDIT:

If you just use one `plot` statement, instead of two in the example above, and fill the entire `layout` with that one invisible plot, then you could add as many `arrows` as you want.  Importantly, you probably would have very fine-scale control over the placement of those `arrows` via the x and y coordinates you give to each arrow.  You would add the `pie` charts over the one `plot` and could probably get the `arrows` to touch the `pie` charts with little trouble via trial and error.