# R Genome Alignment Viewer

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, genome, sequence-alignment

Currently, I have read in a genbank ptt file and used it to plot a genome in R using genoplotR

```
    plot_gene_map(dna_segs=list(mo),xlims=xlims,annotations=annotMED,annotation_height=5,main="Region",gene_type="side_blocks",dna_seg_scale=TRUE, scale=FALSE)
```

I have also read in its corresponding sorted bam file and used rbamtools to make a coverage plot

```
    start<-130000
    end<-140000
    coords<-as.integer(c(0,start,end))
    range<-bamRange(reader,coords)
    bamClose(reader)
    ad<-alignDepth(range)

    add<-data.frame(ad@pos, ad@depth)

    count<-bamCountAll(reader,verbose=TRUE)

    ggplot(add, aes(x=ad.pos, y=ad.depth)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity", position="dodge") + theme_bw()
```

I would now like to overlay these two figures on one graph so we would have a basic genome alignment viewer in R.  However, I'm stuck trying to overlay these two figures, as well as matching up there corresponding positions on the x axis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with **viewports**, as in this thread here:

[Combine base and ggplot graphics in R figure window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window)