# R put together traditional plot and ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have 2 graphs, a map plotted with `ggplot2` like this:

```
w<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=dep_shp.df, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=classJenks))+

  #   scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(40, 100))+
  labs(title ="Classification de la proportion de producteurs par départements
       \n par la methode de jenks (2008)")+
  theme_bw()+
  coord_equal()
```

and a graph as object of type `classIntervals`  from the `classInt` library.

I would like to put together this 2 graphs. I have tried:

```
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))

#creation
print(u, vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(v, vp = vplayout(1, 2))
```

And something with `grid.arrange`

```
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

but none of these work.

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window

Comment: Yes !!! Great rawr thank's !!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method is described in the `Embedding base graphics plots in grid viewports` section of the [`gridBase` vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf).

The `gridBase` package contains functions to set sensible parameters for the plotting region of the base plot.  So we need these packages:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridBase)
```

Here's an example ggplot:

```
a_ggplot <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```

The trick seems to be to call `plot.new` before you set `par`, otherwise it's liable to get confused and not correctly honour the settings.  You also need to set `new = TRUE` so a new page isn't started when you call `plot`.

```
#Create figure window and layout
plot.new()
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))

#Draw ggplot
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1))
print(a_ggplot, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()

#Draw bsae plot
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 2))
par(fig = gridFIG(), new = TRUE)
with(cars, plot(speed, dist))
popViewport()
```

Comment: what is the gridFIG() ??

Comment: @Antoni It aligns the coordinates of the base plot figure region to the current grid viewport.  See `?gridBase::gridFIG`.

Comment: I do not think `grid.newpage()` is needed. When using `png` to save the plot, it produces two png files, one in blank and the other with the desired output. When removing `grid.newpage()`, just one file is created.