# R: plot grid objects using par(mfrow)

Tags: r, plot, grid, meta

I would like to plot grid objects and base R objects on the same png. The package I am using (meta) uses the grid graphics system.

I would like to use mfrow for this if possible, as it is what I am using elsewhere.

If I plot:

```
png("test.png",width=297,height=210,units="mm",res=300)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(1,1)
plot(1,1)
plot(1,1)
plot(1,1)
dev.off()
```

Everything works fine.

However if I plot:

```
library(meta)
m <- metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40))
png("test.png",width=297,height=210,units="mm",res=300)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(1,1)
forest(m,new=F)
plot(1,1)
forest(m,new=F)
dev.off()
```

Things aren't right as the forest plots try to take up the whole page rather than being restricted to their corners.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I bet it behaves similar to heatmap() plots, see [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/par-mfrow-for-heatmap-plots-td4742569.html).

Possible example for a solution from the post (didn't test):

--snip // Citation (Dr Paul Murrell)--

```
library(gridGraphics) 
grid.newpage() 
pushViewport(viewport(0, .5, .5, .5, just=c("left", "bottom"))) 
grid.echo(function() { heatmap(test) }, newpage=FALSE) 
popViewport() 
pushViewport(viewport(.5, 0, .5, .5, just=c("left", "bottom"))) 
grid.echo(function() { heatmap(test) }, newpage=FALSE) 
popViewport()
```

--snip--

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426436/combining-grid-table-and-base-package-plots-in-r-figure), you can combine them into a plot, but I think the margins and settings for `forest()` needs to be optimized so that the titles etc can be seen properly:

```
library(gridBase)
library(gridExtra)

layout(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1),widths=c(1,3))
par(mar=c(2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5))

plot(1,1)

plot.new()
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$figure)
vp1 <-plotViewport()
forest(m,new=FALSE)
popViewport()
```

[image]