# Combine integrated R plots with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a layout plot that merges 3 plots. I want the first plot in the first row and the other ones in  the second row like this image:

[image: plot layout]

The problem comes when I try to combine plots integrated in R and a plot made with **ggplot2** library.
My code is the following:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1,
                2, 3), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
layout.show(n=3)
qplot(area_mean,
      geom="histogram",
      binwidth = 5,  
      main = "ggplot area min histogram", 
      xlab = "Age",  
      fill=I("blue"), 
      col=I("red"), 
      alpha=I(.2),
      xlim=c(0,3000))
hist(area_mean, col="purple", main="Histogram of area mean")
boxplot(area_mean, col="cyan", main="Boxplot of area mean")
```

Then my output image is:

[image: combined layout plot]

Why qplot doesn't appear? I am missing something?

Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window#14125565

Comment: You are right, i didn't found this answer. It really helps

Comment: Did you try patchwork?

Comment: Patchwork only accepts ggplot objects (as do gridExtra and cowplot). To mix base R and ggplot plots, you need gridBase

Comment: I used print() function with layout and it works perfectly. GridBase is also an alternative so there are multiple solutions. Thank you all