# Combining histogram and a line graph

Tags: r, line, histogram

I have created histogram and a line graph whose y-axis values are different as shown.

[image: Histogram]

[image: Line graph]

I want to have the two graphs in one plot.

Comment: Could you please include in your question the code that you used to generate your two current plots?

Comment: You are asking just for two plots on one page? One of which is a `ggplot2` product and the other is a base `plot` result? I'm pretty sure this has been asked and answered. So you should first search (possibly adding the search term `gridBase`) and if you find the existing answers cannot deliver the desired result then p[edit] your question to reflect this and stated how they fail to deliver the necessary results.

Comment: If there's no response within a suitable period of time, say 2 hours, to the two comments, then I suggest closing as a highly probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine base and ggplot graphics in R figure window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution with basic plot:

```
set.seed(16011991)
x <- rnorm(100)
dots <- data.frame(c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3),c(10,20,30,40,30,20,10))
hist(x)
lines(dots, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ust.png)

Or ggplot:

```
set.seed(16011991)
x <- data.frame(norm = rnorm(100))
dots <- data.frame(x=seq(-3,3,0.05), y=log(1:length(seq(-3,3,0.05))))

ggplot(data = x, aes(x=norm, color='red')) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30, fill="white", show.legend = FALSE, size=1.1) +
  geom_line(data = dots, aes(x=x,y=y), color= 'blue', size=1.1) +
  labs(title= 'My histogram', x = 'N(0,1)', y='Count') +
  theme_stata()
```

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO0uQ.png)

in ggplot you can scale the axes if you need to do this to make your graph