# Multiple qgraph and bootnet plots in same pdf

Tags: r, graph, network-analysis, r-qgraph

I would like to merge multiple plots into the same figure, and have tried to use these two commands:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

It works fine when I plot the *qgraph* network plot, but when I get to printing the centrality indices or the centrality stability plot, they are displayed in full screen.

Does anyone here know how I can resize them? And also maybe rotate them so that the X-values are dropped down vertically?

Answer (score 0):

The *qgraph* and *bootnet* packages plot graphs using base R and centrality indices (and stability) using *ggplot2*. Combining these is not easy, but there are some tips for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window). It might be easiest to just export both seperatly and use a third party editor to place them next to each other for a publication though.