# "know" inside a function if current plot is base-graphics

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, r-base-graphics

Is there a way to know programmatically *and non-destructively* whether the current graphics device is base graphics?

I need this to be non-destructive, in that it doesn't open a new device, close the current device, or otherwise modify it (e.g., adding points/lines, etc).

For instance,

```r
isbasegx <- function() {
  length(dev.list()) > 0 && # dev.interactive() && 
    !identical(par("usr"), c(0, 1, 0, 1))
}
```

(*Edited* to remove `dev.interactive()`, as this is intended to be useful in report-generation as well.)

That might be a start, but anything that relies on `par()` is going to fail since grid-based graphics do not update them (this is not a surprise):

```r
plot(1, 1)
par1 <- par()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) # same graphics device
par2 <- par()
all(mapply(identical, par1, par2))
# [1] TRUE
```

What other "hints" at graphics type are there?

Comment: I'd suggest sending a bug report to Hadley (Wickham) and/or the R-dev team,  to see if they can mod all graphics code to check.  After all, your minifunction there will fail for every user who sets his default parameters to anything other than the 0,1,0,1 you stuck in there :-( .   Have you played with `lattice` to see whether it "behaves" ?

Comment: Funny, thanks @CarlWitthoft, I hope you're kidding about the bug report. I'm looking at `grid::` now, haven't found anything definitive, perhaps `lattice::` is next.

Comment: The graphics device is something like "png", "pdf" or "RStudioGD". The device doesn't track how data was added to it, right? As far as I know base and grid aren't graphics devices themselves, they are APIs for interacting with the graphics device. And once the pixels are on the cavas, it's not easy to know how they got there.

Comment: I'm guessing you're familiar with `viewports` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window   .    I still think that, if there is not a function "hiding" somewhere that tells you which tools are controlling the graphics window, that at the least this should be a feature request for  base R.

Comment: That's what I thought and am confirming, thanks @MrFlick.

Comment: @MrFlick  Now I'm wondering if TheRealQuestion here isn't about **device** but rather the **window** in question?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes, I'm familiar (somewhat) with `viewports`, and the `baseViewports()` in that linked question didn't provide a clear path to me atm. Good point about "window", though ... this could be used in automated reports, which suggests I need to remove the notion of `dev.interactive()`, thanks for helping me through that.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in R, the graphics device does not have two mutually exclusive "modes" that we can classify as base R graphics or grid graphics. These are just the (?only) two different graphics APIs that we can use to draw pixels onto a plotting device in R. In fact, the following code example demonstrates that it is perfectly possible to mix and match:

```r
library(grid)
  
plot(1:10)
par(new = TRUE)
grid.rect(width = 0.5, height = 0.5, gp = gpar(lwd = 3), name = "gr")
lines(2:6, c(6, 4, 5, 6, 1), col = 'red')
```

[image]

Here, we have drawn a scatterplot in base R graphics, then drawn a rectangle using grid, then drawn a red line over the top in base R graphics again.

When we have drawn the above image, we cannot say that the current graphics device 'is' base R or 'is' grid. It *contains* graphics primitives that were drawn using calls to both.

---

**EDIT**

If you are trying to work out whether the last plot was a ggplot or a base R graphics, you could try interrogating the contents of `recordPlot`, which keeps a record of the calls that drew the graphics primitives. Therefore, you can do something like:

```r
is_it_a_ggplot <- function() {
  'ggplot2' %in% unlist(lapply(recordPlot()[1][[1]], function(x) {
    x <- x[[2]][[1]]
    if('name' %in% names(x)) x$name else as.character(x)
  }))
}

is_it_base <- function() {
  'C_plot_new' %in% unlist(lapply(recordPlot()[1][[1]], function(x) {
    x <- x[[2]][[1]]
    if('name' %in% names(x)) x$name else as.character(x)
  }))
}

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, col = Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
is_it_a_ggplot()
#> [1] TRUE
is_it_base()
#> [1] FALSE

plot(1:10)
```

[image]

```r
is_it_a_ggplot()
#> [1] FALSE
is_it_base()
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: That was one of my assumptions from the start, I'm hoping to be wrong on that. The response so far from y'all is not reassuring that I'll find a magic function. Thanks @AllanCameron!

Comment: @r2evans interrogating `recordPlot` is worth a look. See my update

Comment: Genius AllanCameron! I had started looking at `recordPlot` noting that it had some differences, but I must have crossed my eyes the first few times I looked at the output. This works well enough for what I was hoping, and is short/fast to boot. Awesome!

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that it isn't working in non-visible graphic devices. For instance, `plot(1);is_it_base()` is true but `svg("/tmp/foo.svg");plot(1);is_it_base();dev.off()` is not ... I might still accept it (perhaps with suggested edits) since it is a huge move in the right direction.

Comment: But can you call `grid` first and then overlay a `plot` call?

Comment: @r2evans The last line of `?recordPlot` gives some hope: *The displaylist can be turned on and off using `dev.control`. Initially recording is on for screen devices, and off for print devices.* If you run `dev.control(displaylist="enable")` after starting the `svg` device `is_it_base()` works as expected.

Comment: While that is encouraging, it must be done before any other plotting code, which does not meet the hope of executing this at an arbitrary point to see if something previous plotted something in base graphics or not. If I put `dev.control(..)` inside of `is_it_base`, then it nullifies the `unlist(..)` vector. Nice thought! I'll keep looking at it @RobertHacken